# Does web audio oscillator type not work in Chrome, Firefox?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, audio, web-audio-api

I seem to just get sine waves no matter what.

```
oscillator = context.createOscillator();
oscillator.type = 1;
```

I notice that this example I found online works on Safari, gives me just a sine wave on chrome, and doesn't work on firefox (maybe because it uses oscillator.noteOn instead of oscillator.start?):

http://middleearmedia.com/web-audio-api-oscillators/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use start(), and .type is a string type:

```
oscillator = context.createOscillator();
oscillator.type = "sawtooth";
oscillator.start(0);
```

See http://updates.html5rocks.com/2014/07/Web-Audio-Changes-in-m36.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I keep running into old descriptions of the web audio API. Do you know where the best place is to look for things like the type of oscillator.type?

Comment: This is the best place to get the updated web audio spec documentation. http://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/